# Dojo - Promise Can't Access Variables

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri, wms, arcgis-js-api

I am working with dojo in the ESRI Web App Builder and have come across a situation where I need to run an AJAX call and still access a variable from the base class. Below is my code with comments in it to explain exactly where it is successful and exactly where it is failing:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'jimu/BaseWidget', 'dojo/request', "esri/layers/WMSLayer", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"], function (declare, BaseWidget, request, WMSLayer, esriConfig) {

    return declare([BaseWidget], {
        baseClass: 'jimu-widget-mywidget',
        // This function is called by a button press (Normally the WMSLayer variable would be set by user input)
        addWms: function () {
            var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer", {
                format: "png",
                visibleLayers: [2]
            });

            this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer); // this.map is inherited from BaseWidget as far as I can see. This adds a wms to my map without error

            request("request.html").then(function(data){
                var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer", {
                    format: "png",
                    visibleLayers: [2]
                });

                this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer); // This is now in another context....I get the error HERE. 
                // At this point map is not defined because this anonymous function is running
                // in a different context. ( at least I think that's what is happening )
            }, function(err){
                // Hopefully there are no typos in my example XD
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My question is --> How do I access the "map" variable from withing the callback function of "request"?

I want to be able to run this.map.addLayers from my call to the GetCapabilities of a WMS service. The request would normally call it and I get all the way to the end of my code until I can't access the "map" variable anymore as I know it.

Dojo type answer is preferred but plain old javaScript is also fine. Please avoid JQuery answers.

Resources are:

[ESRI JavaScript library](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) 
 
[Dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) 

[ESRI Web App Builder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is the classic problem of execution context being lost when an asynchronous callback is invoked (and thus `this` no longer means what you want).  There are generally two ways to resolve this.

One way is to create a variable in the outer scope that references what `this` is, so that the inner function can access it:

```
var self = this;
request('request.html').then(function (data) {
    // ...

    self.map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
});
```

The other way is to use context binding, either via `Function#bind` (ES5) or `dojo/_base/lang.hitch`:

```
// Function#bind:
request('request.html').then(function (data) {
    // ...

    this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
}.bind(this));

// lang.hitch:
request('request.html').then(lang.hitch(this, function (data) {
    // ...

    this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
}));
```

It's also common with the binding approach to break out the asynchronous handler function to another internal instance method:

```
_addRequestedLayer: function () {
    // ...

    this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
},

addWms: function () {
    // ...

    // ES5:
    request('request.html').then(this._addRequestedLayer.bind(this));
    // ...or lang.hitch, with late binding:
    request('request.html').then(lang.hitch(this, '_addRequestedLayer'));
```

There is also a [tutorial on lang.hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hitch/index.html).

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it's the one I used. Both work though.

Answer (score 3):

In your request callback, `this` does not refer to your class anymore. A simple way to have access to the map in the callback is assigning the reference of the map in a variable on addWms function scope and then using it in your callback:

```
addWms: function() {
    var map = this.map;
    // Your code here
    request('request.html').then(function (data) {
        // Your code here
        map.addLayer(wmsLayer); // Note that you're using map instead of this.map
    }
}
```

You can also use Dojo hitch function, where you can pass a function and the context that it should be applied. I suggest that you take a look at this link http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch.